# Why is purple the color that protects from witches' curse?

Tags: european-folklore, witchcraft

I was watching some history channel show about cursed placed, and they featured Romanian witches who cursed the central government for a tax policy.

> Witchcraft is not taken lightly in Romania. After losing a 2009 election, former foreign minister Mircea Geoana accused president Traian Basescu of using the mystical “power of the purple flame” to damage his campaign and of employing a parapsychologist to attack him with “negative energy”.

<sub>Source: [Witches curse as Romania spells out plans to tackle false predictions; Irish Times, 2020/12/16](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/witches-curse-as-romania-spells-out-plans-to-tackle-false-predictions-1.567995)</sub>

In the show they showed members of parliament wearing purple as a ward against the curses.

> President Traian Basescu and his aides have been known to wear purple on certain days, supposedly to ward off evil.

<sub>Source: [Curses! Romania forces witches, fortune tellers to pay income tax; Syracuse.com, 2011/1/6](https://www.syracuse.com/have-you-heard/2011/01/curses_romanias_witches_forced.html)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This study should answer your question:

[The wizards of the violet flame. A magical mystery tour of Romanian politics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291709799_The_wizards_of_the_violet_flame_A_magical_mystery_tour_of_Romanian_politics) - Journal for the Study of Religions and Ideologies

It presents the manifestations of irrational practices in recent Romanian politics. Providing a short history of the mystical and the occult in Romanian politics, this research uses as a case study the alleged use of the occult "violet flame" in the presidential campaign of 2009.

By showing how public religiousness and the daily mystical practices are changing, the author is describing the transformations of the national political communication under the pressure of the news media, which are becoming more and more pervasive to the occult discourses and the magical thinking.

The author describes these transformations as part of the general transformations of the political imaginary in Romania. The Romanian public psyche belongs more and more to the culture of infotainment, a culture based on cultivating superficiality, where mystical and simplistic thinking have replaced the traditional processes of public exchange of reasonable ideas. Thus a main trait of this video-pathology in which the Romanian media is engulfed, is the substitution of the rational discourses with the superficial understanding of the world and supernatural explanations about the universe. One of the conclusions is that the manifestations and functions of the irrational in the Romanian political sphere have become more innocuously connected with a deep mysticism already in place, and are profoundly changing the society as a whole.